# ^ symbol in R lm()

Tags: r, lm

Running a regression in R:

```
fit = lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + (z-1)^2, data=data)
```

I get ridiculously high R^2 values. I replaced the (z-1)^2 with a variable I'll call q which is defined as (z-1)^2 and I got a much lower R^2 value.

It's now clear to me that ^ doesn't act as an exponent in lm(), but what *does* it do? I looked here http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/richard.hahn/teaching/FormulaNotation.pdf but I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 6):

the term `(z-1)^2` is the same as the interaction `(z-1)*(z-1)`, NOT the square power of (z-1).
If you wanted the formula as literally take, you should use `I()`.
You can see `?I` and `?formula` for further reference,

Comment: Yes, so what exactly does that do? I don't fully understand the interaction part and why that inflated the r^2. Thanks.

Comment: That makes a very good question for stack exchange: what does interaction means in regression. I'm afraid I'm not the most qualified to adequately answer it, though. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Building up on the previous answer, without the `I()` operator the `lm()` does not [interepret](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) the mathematical operators to do math. Therefore, without the `I()`, '`-1`' has a similar effect on `lm()` as using "`+0`" i.e. to not use "`(Intercept)`" term. Hence th `R-squared` values are higher ([details here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo)) because the denominator in `R-squared` calculation becomes `(yi^2)` instead of `(yi - y_bar)^2`. Code below shows the similarities and differences on how `lm()` compute.

```
# Create sample dataframe
x <- 10 + rnorm(100)
y <- 11 + rnorm(100)
z <- 12 + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

**(1) without using the term "`(z-1)`"**

```
lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z), data=df)
summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**# (2) Using the term "(z-1)^2"**
Note: Here, without "`I`" as in "`I((z-1)^2)`" the `lm()` function does not see "`-`, `^`" as the arthmetic operators

```
lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + (z-1)^2, data=df)
summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(3) Without use of `I()` the `lm()` function interpretes "`(z-1)^2`" as interaction "`(z-1)*(z-1)`" denoted by "*"**

```
lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + (z-1)*(z-1), data=df)
summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(4a) Withouth use of `I()` the (3) interaction term may be broken down as below:**

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + (z-1) + (z-1) + (z-1):(z-1), data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(4b) removing paranthesis**

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + z-1 + z-1 + (z-1):(z-1), data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(4c) keeping only "`z:-1`" term**

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + z:-1, data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(4d) works same as (4c)**

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + z-1, data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(5) Without use of "-1", the lm() function uses "Intercept" term**

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + z + z + z:z, data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(6) Using a separate variable does the math part outside lm() function.**

Hence the intercept is included by the `lm()`.

```
var_z <- (z-1)^2
lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + var_z, data=df)
summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]

**(7) Using `I()` inside the `lm()` function:**

It allows it to interprete the mathematical operators to do math. Here, the interecept is included by the `lm()`.

```
 lm.fit <- lm(y ~ x + log(x) + z + log(z) + I((z-1)^2), data=df)
 summary(lm.fit)
```

[image]