# ^ symbol in lm() in R

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I asked this question in Stack Overflow: [^ symbol in R lm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710525/symbol-in-r-lm)

I feel like here would be a better place to get an answer. What exactly does the ^ symbol do to the regression and why does it make the r^2 so much higher?

Comment: Have you looked at `?formula`?

Comment: In most cases of `^` in a formula you are implicitly adding interaction terms. This is what @Sven-Hohenstein is explaining in his answer.  That increases the flexibility of the model which will usually make it possible fit to the data better (in sample).  It might be that the help page for `formula` now makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

In a formula, the `^` operator specifies the degree of the interaction. It is *not* used for exponentiation.

Some examples:

- `x ^ 2` is the same as `x * x` and therefore the same as `x`.
- `(a + b + c) ^ 2` is the same as `a * b + a * c + b * c`. It creates all interactions of two variables.
- `(a + b + c) ^ 3` is the same as `a * b * c`. It creates all interactions including up to three variables: `a + b + c + a:b + a:c + b:c + a:b:c`.

Note. `:` denotes interaction (product).

Comment: But it can be used for exponentiation. For example, "x squared" can be included using `I(x^2)`.